# Are history questions on-topic, or should they be migrated (if possible) to History of Science and Mathematics?

Tags: discussion

[What are the factors that led to the digital revolution?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/575496/238188) I had asked a history question that was closed. One user said it might be better suited for History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. We do have a [history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag here:

> For questions on the history of electricity and electronics.

It isn't clear if history questions are on-topic or not according to the help-center. Help-center says:

- a specific electronics design problem
- the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
- a communication scheme
- the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

History isn't included in this. Are history questions on-topic? If so, should the list in the help-center be changed?

Answer (score 2):

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
> problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
> usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
> entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
> participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
> asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
> explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
> course welcome in our real time web chat.)

As far as migration goes, it needs to be on-topic on their site, so if it can be shown that it is on topic (via the site that the question will go to) then could be migrated.

Comment: How do I show it is on-topic on the other site? My request for migration was declined. What do I do?

Comment: The question cannot be made on topic. This is the third time you have approached the meta site on trying to open the question. Please drop the issue and move on. A lot of the activity on the site that you have generated creates needless work for the mods and other members of the community, please stop.

Comment: So it is not on-topic on History of Science and Mathematics?

Comment: This is the 2nd time, not the 3rd one

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: All right, if it's not going to be migrated, I am going to ask it on History of Science and Mathematics, since it is closed here.

Comment: Please don't do that either, cross site duplication is frowned on (and duplicating closed questions is also frowned on). Let it go.